# To Find the minimum element in an array which is sorted and Rotated

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I recently faced a programming problem which is as follows:

A sorted array is given and the array is rotated at some unknown point, I have to find the minimum element in it. The Array can contain duplicates too.

For eg:

```
 Input: {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4}

 Output: 1  

 Input: {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2}   

 Output: 0
```

I followed simple solution is to traverse trough the complete array and find minimum. This solution requires  time O(n).I understand the fact that the minimum element is the one whose previous element is greater than it. If there is no such element present, then there is no rotation and first element would be the minimum.

But i was asked for a  O(Logn) solution. Is there a way to solve it in in O(Logn) time?

Comment: binary search is the solution for `O(log n)`, you just have to add extra conditions for the rotation.

Comment: You can check this link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-element-in-a-sorted-and-rotated-array/

Comment: Was an interview question for my first job out of college. The interviewer called it a "T-sorted array", but I don't know just how pervasive the term is...

Comment: @vikiiii, you should probably post your link as an answer.

Comment: @Dilum I don' want to take credit as a accepted answer for giving  the link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Note the first entry
- Perform a binary search; at each stage choose the right half if the pivot element is greater than or equal to the stored first element, and the left half if the pivot element is less.

For instance, given `{4,5,6,7,1,2,3}`:

- Pivot at `7` > `4`, reduce to right half `{1,2,3}`
- Pivot at `2` < `4`, reduce to left half `1`.
- Considering only one element, answer is `1`.

Comment: Why would it matter if there are dupes, they would just both be the min

Comment: 0 is the min in the above example and is not duplicated.

Comment: Ah, ok. Choose the RHS if the pivot is greater _or equal_. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @aaronman Because in the worst case the entire array is duplicates except for the min. Then you're searching for the single element which is different, with no hint as to whether it's to the left or right of your current guess.

Comment: @pjs doesn't matter the performance is still log(n), why does a normal binary search still work if all the elements are dupes and your element isn't in the list

Comment: @aaronman Because with a normal binary search you can remove half of the remaining elements from consideration at each step.  Here you can't.  If you guess that the min is to the left of the mid-point, you haven't eliminated the possibility that it could in fact be to the right of the midpoint.

Answer (score 1):

see this :
Since it is sorted array. i need to apply binary search to find pivot..

Lowest element will be where array was pivoted.

Call this `findpivot(arr,0,n-1);`

```
int findPivot(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
   // base cases
   if (high < low)  return -1;
   if (high == low) return low;

   int mid = (low + high)/2;   /*low + (high - low)/2;*/
   if (mid < high && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1])
     return mid;
   if (mid > low && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
     return (mid-1);
   if (arr[low] >= arr[mid])
     return findPivot(arr, low, mid-1);
   else
     return findPivot(arr, mid + 1, high);
}
```

Comment: orginal post is here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MinElementInRotatedArrayUsingRecursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n1 = arr1.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr1));

        int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n2 = arr2.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr2));

        int arr3[] = { 1 };
        int n3 = arr3.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr3));

        int arr4[] = { 1, 2 };
        int n4 = arr4.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr4));

        int arr5[] = { 2, 1 };
        int n5 = arr5.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr5));

        int arr6[] = { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n6 = arr6.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr6));

        int arr7[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        int n7 = arr7.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr7));

        int arr8[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1 };
        int n8 = arr8.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr8));

        int arr9[] = { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 };
        int n9 = arr9.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr9));

    }// main

    public static int findMin(int[] num) {
        return findMin(num, 0, num.length - 1);
    }

    public static int findMin(int[] num, int start, int last) {
        // only 1 element
        if (start == last)
            return num[start];
        // only 2 elements
        if ((last - start) == 1)
            return Math.min(num[start], num[last]);

        int middle = start + (last - start) / 2;

        // not rotated
        if (num[start] < num[last]) {
            return num[start];
        }

        // go last side
        /*
         * int[] a = 2,3,4,5,1
         *  a[start]=2 and a[last]=1 and a[mid] = 4 
         *  a[mid] > a[start]
         * Then, as the array is rotated, That's why, calculation will start from
         * a[middle] to a[last]
         */
        else if (num[middle] > num[start]) {
            return findMin(num, middle, last);
        } else {

            // go start side
            /*
             * int[] a = 4,5,1,2,3 
             * a[start]= 4 and a[last]=3 and a[mid] = 1 
             * a[mid] < a[start]
             * Then, as the array is rotated, That's why, calculation will start from
             * a[start] to a[middle]
             */
            return findMin(num, start, middle);
        }
    }
}
```

The iterative method:

```
public class MinElementInRotatedArrayUsingRecursionAndIteration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n1 = arr1.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr1));

        int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n2 = arr2.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr2));

        int arr3[] = { 1 };
        int n3 = arr3.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr3));

        int arr4[] = { 1, 2 };
        int n4 = arr4.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr4));

        int arr5[] = { 2, 1 };
        int n5 = arr5.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr5));

        int arr6[] = { 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int n6 = arr6.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr6));

        int arr7[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        int n7 = arr7.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr7));

        int arr8[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1 };
        int n8 = arr8.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr8));

        int arr9[] = { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 };
        int n9 = arr9.length;
        System.out.println("The minimum element is " + findMin(arr9));

    }// main

    // iterative method
    public static int findMin(int[] nums) {


        int start =0; 
        int last =nums.length-1;

        while(start <= last){
            if(nums[start]<=nums[last]) return nums[start];

            int mid =(start + last)/2;
            /*  int[] a =  2,3,4,5,1
             a[start]=2 and a[last]=1
             a[mid] = 4
             a[mid] > a[start] 
            Then, as the array is rotated, That's why, calculation will start from a[middle] to a[last]
    */
            if(nums[mid]>=nums[start]){
                start = mid +1;
            }else{
                /*  int[] a =  4,5,1,2,3
             a[start]= 4 and a[last]=3
             a[mid] = 1
             a[mid] < a[start] 
            Then, as the array is rotated, That's why, calculation will start from a[start] to a[middle]
       */
                last = mid;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find minimum element in a sorted and rotated array in Java**

```
package yourPackageNameGoesHere;

public class yourClassNameGoesHere {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      int arr[]={16,19,21,25,3,5,8,10};
      findMinimumElementInSortedAndRotatedArray(arr);
}

public static void findMinimumElementInSortedAndRotatedArray(int[] arr) {
    int mid = arr.length / 2;
    boolean pivotFound = false;
    int pivotIndex = -1;

    for (int rightSide = mid; rightSide < arr.length - 1; rightSide++) {
        if (arr[rightSide] > arr[rightSide + 1]) {
            pivotIndex = rightSide;
            pivotFound = true;
            System.out.println("1st For Loop. Pivot is: " + arr[pivotIndex] + ". Pivot Index is: " + pivotIndex);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!pivotFound) {
        for (int leftSide = 0; leftSide < mid; leftSide++) {
            if (arr[leftSide] > arr[leftSide + 1]) {
                pivotIndex = leftSide;
                System.out.println("1st For Loop. Pivot is: " + arr[pivotIndex] + ". Pivot Index is: " + pivotIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    String textForSmall = "Smallest Number is ";
    if (pivotIndex != arr.length - 1 && pivotIndex != 0) {
        System.out.println(arr[0] < arr[pivotIndex + 1] ? textForSmall + arr[0] : textForSmall + arr[pivotIndex + 1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println(arr[0] < arr[pivotIndex] ? textForSmall + arr[0] : textForSmall + arr[pivotIndex]);
    }
}
```

}